# Ethernet connection "unclaimed"

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

I have my ethernet cable plugged into my PC, yet it doesn't show up in the GUI list of network devices. I have verified the cable works when plugged into another device. Here's the output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
ajw@Beluga:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: wlp9s0
       version: 00
       serial: 90:e8:68:7b:3d:ad
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8821ce driverversion=6.2.0-35-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.121 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:89 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fcd00000-fcd0ffff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       version: 15
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fcc04000-fcc04fff memory:fcc00000-fcc03fff
```

As you can see, it says "*-network UNCLAIMED". So how do I "claim" it?

Also, here's the output of `ifconfig -a` if that helps:

```
ajw@Beluga:~$ ifconfig -a
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 6066  bytes 513650 (513.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6066  bytes 513650 (513.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lxcbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.3.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.3.255
        ether 00:16:3e:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp9s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1440
        inet 192.168.0.121  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 2607:fb91:21c:863b:706c:4d24:6191:2b9e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2607:fb91:21c:863b:8375:f9dc:8e30:5bf1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::3f0e:7eda:143f:7caf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 90:e8:68:7b:3d:ad  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 64745  bytes 58027210 (58.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 49696  bytes 10214099 (10.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Providing your OS & release details are helpful; as a starting point.  *`ifconfig` is a deprecated command; is your system really old?*

Comment: I have Kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `sudo modprobe r8169` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep r816`

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your ethernet port if you haven't done so already.  You can't just plug in a RJ45 patch cord from a LAN device/switch and expect routing to just configure itself, right?

[image]

There seems to be an assigned IP address (10.0.3.1).  But that may not even be the ethernet port.  And no default gateway.  The 10.0 subnet is unroutable so packets won't be going anywhere besides the LAN.  If you look at the various folders in the network settings app you'll probably see something like DHCP not being turned on.  I'm assuming you haven't got an assigned IP address.

`ping` and `arp` are your friend

Comment: It was working before this, I just turned on my PC and it didn't show up. Also I don't have access to the menu you are showing because I'm using KDE plasma

Comment: "It worked before" is pretty meaningless, right?  Something obviously broke.  Start at the NIC card and work your way from the physical layer to the network layer to troubleshoot this.

Comment: @jones0610 If the device is unclaimed; i.e. there is no driver loaded, then there is no interface to be configured. It will not appear in the Network Manager GUI at all.

Comment: I found the issue, the realtek drivers must have gotten uninstalled. Problem fixed now

Comment: @AJ Wu:  You're welcome.  Starting at the physical layer and seeing that the drivers were no longer there solved your problem.  "It was working before this" is something I hear a lot from people who dismiss obvious troubleshooting practices.  I hope you learned something here.  Never assume anything.  Always troubleshoot bottom up or top down.  Best of luck to you!